# only one select query is showing in excel worksheet

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005, excel-2007

I've call a stored procedure (SQL Server 2005) in Excel 2007. This SP has two select statements, however in excel worksheet, result of first statement is showing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note: OP is not using VBA. Question originally had the VBA tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used VBA to populate the sheet with resultset and this resolved the issue. I had to also write code for iterating through all the resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

If your stored procedure has two select statements, you will have two recordsets returned. Make sure you are writing both to the worksheet. You should also verify that both select statements are returning rows.

**NOTE:** If you'd like to try this using VBA, chapter 19 of the book [Professional Excel Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321508793) is devoted to interacting with SQL Server. The chapter walks you through connecting to the database, executing stored procedures, and writing the results back to your workbook. All of the code you need is provided, along with good explanations of what it does. And if you're new to VBA, this book is on the short-list of ones you should pick up. Check out [good books to learn Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777674/138938) for others.

Here is an example of part of a sub that returns 5 record sets from a stored procedure:

```
     If Not rsData.EOF Then

        ' The first recordset contains prices
        Sheet39.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Set rsData = rsData.NextRecordset

        ' The second recordset contains products
        Sheet39.Range("a20").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Set rsData = rsData.NextRecordset

        ' The third recordset contains stores
        Sheet39.Range("a35").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Set rsData = rsData.NextRecordset

        ' The fourth recordset contains payment types
        Sheet39.Range("j1").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Set rsData = rsData.NextRecordset

        ' The fifth recordset contains customers
        Sheet39.Range("j8").CopyFromRecordset rsData
        Set rsData = rsData.NextRecordset

    Else
        MsgBox "No data located.", vbCritical, "Error!"
    End If
```

Comment: Presently, I'm using connection wizard which lets me mention the sp name.  How would I write both recordsets to the worksheet?

Comment: Can you post the code of your sp and any vba that you're using? That will help us figure out what you can do.

Comment: SP has two select statements: alter procedure testSP AS begin select * from table1 select * from table2 end. I'm not using any VBA. I'm referring to http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/06/08/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba.aspx

Comment: Not sure you can return multiple result sets with your approach. Can you break the stored procedure into 2 and write each to a different place in your workbook?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing now. Do you know if any approach is possible with VBA? I'm novice in this and know lil' about VBA.

Comment: Gargi, the VBA approach is very easy, but you'll need to spend a little time getting it set up. If you're working with Excel on a regular basis, it's time well spent. Give it a shot and I can help if you get stuck.